# Swift – Embed a long UIView inside a Container View

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uicontainerview

### The Overall Description.

[image]

I have an app where I'd like to contain a view that's very long horizontally. I have tried to simply use options such as a UIScrollView or a UIPageView, but because of very specific reasons regarding my code, I have decided it would be easiest to programmatically move the image along.

---

### My Main Goal Here . . .

Once I get this long view contained inside the main View Controller (on the top of my screenshot above), I will use code to simply move everything to the left. For example:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.page1Label.transform =
        self.page1Label.transform.translatedBy(x: -375.0, y: 0.0)
        self.page2Label.transform =
        self.page2Label.transform.translatedBy(x: -375.0, y: 0.0)
        ...
}
```

This is only possible if I am able to contain everything inside a very wide view. I'd hopefully like to keep everything within the storyboard, and not need any code at all. But all I need is to be able to have that bottom view controller (with all the colors) to be *inside* that upper view controller. I have inserted a Container View in the upper view controller because that's what I'm assuming I'll need, but I don't know.

---

### The Problem With My Current Solution

When I contain that really wide, colorful view controller inside the upper, screen-width Container View, it doesn't keep the original width of the colorful view. Instead, it squishes it into the size of the Container View it's embedded in. So I really just need it to be a wide view that continues in all its glory beyond the boundaries of the iPhone screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a scrollview with paging turned on.  You are going to have to adjust the width based on device width anyways, but if you want to do it with the transform (which will screw up any touch handling that you do because transforms are applied after autolayout and its not recommended that you use them for sizing and positioning -- they are for transitory animations)then what you need to do is make your container view as big as the thing its containing.  Right now the rainbow view is getting squished to the width of the container which happens to be one screen wide.  If its supposed to be 5 screens wide remove your existing width constraint and add one that is equal to 5X the width of the superview, which will cause it to run off the right edge of the viewcontroller which is actually what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use scrollview with paging turned on.
Here is give you small example.

1) First Simulated Size = Freeform.

- here is Viewcontroller width 1125(375*3). You can used your size.

Here is Screenshot display Simulated Size and Viewcontroller width

[image]

2)Add ScrollView in Viewcontroller.

- Enable Paging

Here is Screenshot display ScrollView and Enable Paging.

[image]

You have to Use with normal ScrollView with Paging coding.
Let me know you can More help.

**Note** : When you used ScrollView with Paging than Animation is normal Paging Animation. so you want to Some Animation than you can manage with contain Programmatically. Let me know you can not satisfied with this answer. I will give you more Detail also Edit your Question with more Detail.

Comment: I haven't the time to try this out right now, but once I do, I'll comment whether or not it worked. Thanks for the help.